# Finding formula for 2 number series relationship

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I'm not very skilled at math, so please bear with me.

I have 2 numbers of rows with numbers, and i'm trying to find the relationship between the two, or a formula of how to go from A to B.

Column A consist of:

```
-34,4472
-28,8912
-23,3352
-17,7792
-12,2232
-6,6672
-1,1112
4,4448
10,0008
15,5568
21,1128
26,6688
32,2248
37,7808
43,3368
```

Column B consist of:

```
0,258439095255309
0,23109104284734
0,203742990439371
0,176394938031401
0,149046885623433
0,121698833215463
0,0943507808074938
0,0670027283995246
0,0396546759915554
0,0123066235835862
0,0109392209631876
0,00957181834278922
0,00820441572239076
0,0068370131019923
0,00546961048159384
```

The relationship is, that A: -34,4472 corresponds to B: 0,258439095255309, and so forth down the columns. (I couldn't draw and Excel sheet here)

I am trying to find a formula so that i can determine:
"If A is -30, then B is ___"

Is this possible, and how should i go about solving this?

Comment: No better way than plotting this data as a set of points $(A_k,B_k)$ in order to anticipate a formula, example an affine formula $B_k \approx mA_k+p$. Maybe you will have to take the $log(B_k)$ instead of the $B_k$, etc.

Comment: Any comment ?...